# Formulas without efficient algorithms?

Tags: big-picture

Suppose the fastest known method to multiply two decimal numbers is an exponential time algorithm. Would it still be beneficial to mathematics having formulas like the following for positive integers?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac {n(n + 1)}{2}$$

Comment: It is always benefical to have such formulas because they are valid for all input and the time/complexity of numerical computation is of subordinated  importance.

Comment: Even in the applied world, exponential time (in terms of digits) is actually often ok for numerical problems. For a lot of problems a reasonable goal is to get $O(\log(n))$ or even just $O(1)$ digits in $\operatorname{poly}(n)$ time. See e.g. the CS concept of an approximation scheme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme, or look at the bounds given by any sampling-based algorithm like MCMC